# Height is ambiguous

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

*Using Xcode 8.0 (8A218a)*

I get "Height is ambiguous." even though  (in my opinion) I've got constraints all along the Y-axis.

Both of the two subviews inside the view have a height (one have height as constraint, and one as intristic content size).

See the image below for what the "Debug View Hierarchy" says.

[image]

The constraints are created in code with the following code:

label is `UILabel`, underline is `UIView`

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
underline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

addSubview(label)
addSubview(underline)

label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true

label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: underline.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

underline.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
underline.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
underline.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

underline.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0).isActive = true
```

Here's sample-project extracted from the problematic project:
https://github.com/everlof/LayoutIssue

Comment: The label, as you can see from `label.height = 30.5 @ 1000 (content size) `

Comment: xcode version is?

Comment: Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce it a smaller project and share that

Comment: @Mr.Bista https://github.com/everlof/LayoutIssue I managed to reproduce it, check the project. There are some more issues in this project, but the one in the question is about UnderlineHeadingView and UILabel of CellContentView

Comment: I ran your app, but the debugger view is empty with not errors and warning with Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a bug in Xcode 8.0 then